# Perl: array goes empty after passing it to a function?

Tags: arrays, perl, subroutine, bioperl

I'm working on a project that's scalating a lot, lately, and I'm re-writing code to make it more OOP and passing all redundant code into sub-routines.

The script checks whether a gene exists in the database (through various means) or not. It may also report possible duplicates. Before reporting a duplicate, the script makes sure it's not a "biological duplicate" (essentially the same biological data but a with different position in the genome and, hence, not an actual duplicate). In order to do so...

```
 my @gene_ids;
 my @gene_names;                                

 while(my $gene = $geners_bychecksum->next){

        my $gene_name = $gene->gene_name;
        my $gene_id = $gene->gene_id;

        push @gene_ids, $gene_id;
        push @gene_names, $gene_name;


    }

    print STDERR "$id\tJ\tALERT CHECKSUM MULTI-HIT\t(".join(",",@gene_names).")\n"; 
    my $solve_multihit = solve_multihit($id, \@gene_names, \@gene_ids, $spc, $species_directory, $dataset);
    print STDERR "$id\tJ\tALERT CHECKSUM MULTI-HIT\t(".join(",",@gene_names).")\n"; 

    if($solve_multihit){

        print STDERR "$id\tM\tUPDATE \n";   
        print $report "$id\tM\tUPDATE \n";  
        $countM++;                                                                              

    } else {

        print STDERR "$id\tJ\tALERT CHECKSUM MULTI-HIT\t(".join(",",@gene_names).")\n"; 

    }
```

Here, `$geners_bychecksum` is a DBIC resulset with database hits from a prior search and, for this case-scenario, it always has more than 1 gene. The `$id`,`$spc`,`$species_directory` and `$dataset` are all strings that come from the config and are defined above this chunk.

The `solve_multihit` subroutine is a rather complicated function that tries to resolve whether the multi-hits are actual duplicates or biological duplicates. Notice that I'm passing the `@gene_names` and `@gene_ids` arrays to this function. This function will return the gene_id of the proper gene, if it was able to solve the discrepancy; or 0 if not. Simplified code for the sub can be found in the following link

https://codeshare.io/2EM8qN

**THE ACTUAL QUESTION**

You may have noticed that the

`print STDERR "$id\tJ\tALERT CHECKSUM MULTI HIT\t(".join(",",@gene_names).")\n";`

is both before and after the `solve_multihit` subroutine call... and the array seems to go empty after running the function, according to the STDERR:

```
BBOV_I005030    J   ALERT CHECKSUM MULTI-HIT    (XP_001609152.1,XP_001609157.1)
BBOV_I005030    J   ALERT CHECKSUM MULTI-HIT    ()
BBOV_I005040    J   ALERT CHECKSUM MULTI-HIT    (XP_001609156.1,XP_001609153.1)
BBOV_I005040    J   ALERT CHECKSUM MULTI-HIT    ()
BBOV_I005050    J   ALERT CHECKSUM MULTI-HIT    (XP_001609154.1,XP_001609155.1)
BBOV_I005050    J   ALERT CHECKSUM MULTI-HIT    ()
BBOV_I005060    J   ALERT CHECKSUM MULTI-HIT    (XP_001609154.1,XP_001609155.1)
BBOV_I005060    J   ALERT CHECKSUM MULTI-HIT    ()
BBOV_I005070    J   ALERT CHECKSUM MULTI-HIT    (XP_001609156.1,XP_001609153.1)
BBOV_I005070    J   ALERT CHECKSUM MULTI-HIT    ()
BBOV_I005080    J   ALERT CHECKSUM MULTI-HIT    (XP_001609152.1,XP_001609157.1)
BBOV_I005080    J   ALERT CHECKSUM MULTI-HIT    ()
```

Why would that happen? I'm pretty sure I could solve it by returning the arrays along with the results of the `solve_multihit{}` sub, but I wonder why would it go empty.

PS: The **J** in the report is just a case-scenario key code.

Comment: There's obviously something in `solve_multihit()` which modifies the input arrays (definitely `@gene_names`, possibly also `@gene_ids`), but we can only guess at what that "something" is without seeing what's in the sub. Is it maybe using `shift` or `pop` to access the contents of the array(s)?

Comment: I didn't know I could be modifying the imput! I'll add the sub to the post. Thanks

Comment: @zdim, Re "*The function arguments are aliased, and if you change @_ you change them.*", Changing `@_` wouldn't have the decribed effect. Changing `@{ $_[1] }` would.

Comment: @ikegami  Right, thank you. It was a rushed and clumsy "fix" of an initial comment which was imprecise to the point of being wrong. I'm removing the comment.  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two ways for your code to accomplish the data removal that it seems to be doing.

The function arguments available in `@_` are aliased to data passed to it.  So if you change `@_` itself (or its elements) you change the data outside of the function.

More likely, as you are passing by reference, your sub probably works directly with it

```
sub ff {
    my ($rary) = @_;
    @$rary = ();
}

my @data = 1..4;

ff(\@data);

say for @data;  # empty
```

If your processing needs to change the array it works with then make a local copy first

```
sub ff { 
    my ($rary) = @_;
    my @local_ary = @$ary;
    # now changes to @local_ary do not affect @data in the caller
}
```

This is generally safer, while it does introduce a data copy which doesn't happen when working with the reference.

---

The edit together with ikegami's answer clears this up: [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) is destructive to the array it works with and here by curious syntax it's fed an anonymous array formed out of a dereferenced `@_` argument, whereby it changes the data in the caller.

There is no reason for `splice` in what you do.  Its purpose *is* to change the array.

Instead, use arrayrefs that are passed to the sub

```
sub solve_multihit {
    my ($id, $gene_names, $gene_ids, ...) = @_;
    foreach my $name (@$gene_names) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

or make a local copy if you wish

```
sub solve_multihit { 
    my $id = shift;
    my @gene_names = @{ shift @_ };
    ...
}
```

where `my @gene_names` is a lexical variable in this scope (the sub in your case ) and changes to it do not affect the one with the same name in the calling scope.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I missing something... How can I access the elements in $gene_names after storing it like that? a quick debug over the @_ values shows this:

  foreach my $var (values @_){
   
    print STDERR $var."\n"; 
  
  }

BBOV_I001860 |
ARRAY(0x3fa6180) <--- gene_names |
ARRAY(0x3fa5898) <--- gene_ids |
bbo |
bbo |
omcl |

Comment: @LionelUranLandaburu Then you work with an _arrayref_.  You can access an element by `$$arrayref[0]` or by `$arrayref->[0]` (better when code is more complex).  You can iterate by, say,  `for my $elem (@$arrayref) { ... }`.  Etc.  I'd suggest to _not use `@_` directly_.  Just say 'no'.

Comment: @LionelUranLandaburu  Btw, the `values` that you use had been intended to return values of a hash, and had until v5.12 only worked with a hash. Using it with an array may cause confusion. More importantly, if you want values of an array it's enough to say `foreach my $var (@array)`.

Comment: @LionelUranLandaburu  When you do `\@data` you take a _reference_ to the array, getting a scalar variable much like a pointer. That reference is what you pass to your sub.  Then you need to _dereference_ it in order to access the elements, and my comment above is about that.  See [perfreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Comment: @LionelUranLandaburu  Added an example of how to access arrayref elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
my @gene_names = splice(shift);
my @gene_ids   = splice(shift);
```

is short for

```
my @gene_names = splice(@{ shift(@_) });
my @gene_ids   = splice(@{ shift(@_) });
```

`splice(@a)` empties the array and returns its contents. There's no reason to do that! The above should be

```
my @gene_names = @{ shift(@_) };
my @gene_ids   = @{ shift(@_) };
```

Honestly, there's no need to make a copy of the array. Just use the provided reference.

```
my $gene_names = shift;
my $gene_ids   = shift;
```

I'd provide a fixed-up version of `solve_multihit`, but it has numerous major problems I can't fix with the information I have.